# In R, is it possible to use a dynamic formula for matrix row and column indices?

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, lapply

The below section of code works fine for pulling values out of a vertically expanding matrix, reaching down one added row at a time (please pay particular attention to my note in the code of `# <<` ):

```
plotData <- reactive({
    req(dim(sanitizedMat())[1] >= 1)
    lapply(seq_len(nrow(sanitizedMat())),
           function(i){
             tibble(
               Scenario = rownames(sanitizedMat())[i],
               X = 1:input$periods,
               Y = interpol(input$periods, sanitizedMat()[i, 1:2]) # << note the matrix index [i,1:2]
             )
           }) %>% bind_rows()
  })
```

However, in my attempt to reorient the matrix reading to horizontal in data pairings of 2, I'd like to make a change to matrix indices as shown below where the `interpol()` function is applied to Y (emphasis on note `# <<` ):

```
plotData <- reactive({
    req(dim(sanitizedMat())[1] >= 1)
    lapply(seq_len(ncol(sanitizedMat()))/2,
           function(i){
             tibble(
               Scenario = rownames(sanitizedMat())[i],
               X = 1:input$periods,
               Y = interpol(input$periods, sanitizedMat()[1, i*2-1:i*2]) # << note attempt to use formula for matrix index
             )
           }) %>% bind_cols()
  })
```

Is it possible to use a formula for matrix indices, like I try above with `[1, i*2-1:i*2]`? If it is possible, I'm pretty sure my syntax is wrong but this shows the idea.

This would allow me to skip along the matrix horizontally, in leaps of 2 columns as `lapply` iterates via `i`.

Comment: eventually `[1, (i*2-1):(i*2)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to post [How to automatically delete a matrix column in R if there otherwise would be subscript out of bounds error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69601804/how-to-automatically-delete-a-matrix-column-in-r-if-there-otherwise-would-be-sub) which reflects dynamic matrix indexing and provides completely resolved code.